# Adjust font size in imported pgf

Tags: tikz-pgf

I generate plots with Matlab and would like to export them to a Latex based report. I found the matfig2pgf script pretty cool, since it adjusts to the document font. One problem I have though, is that the standard font size is way too large for the legend entries and exceeds the box. 
I found that the entries are generated through a \pgftext class, but could not find an option to change the applied font size. 
Is there a way to do that? Axis label etc are fine in my 12pt, just need the legend to be set to 10pt.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi Jakob, welcome to the site! Do you have a particular reason for using `matfig2pgf` instead of `matlab2tikz`?

Comment: There is not. Tried it now though, works a lot better. Thanks

Comment: However, if you might still read this: It automatically formats my tick labelling from 0.01 to 10⁻². Can I suppress that?

Comment: You can insert `\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/fixed}` somewhere in your document before your plot to print the numbers in fixed format.

Comment: ok found it, you need to do:\begin{axis}[
   scaled x ticks = false,
   x tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
   scaled y ticks = false,
   yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
   scale only axis, .... in your tikz file

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was solved by switching to a different tool for converting MATLAB figures.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was solved by switching to a different tool for converting MATLAB figures.